# Why is it wrong to write RETURN ? ( postorder traversal )

Tags: c++

```
void Postorder( IntPtr head ) {
    if ( head != NULL ) {
        return Postorder( head -> left ); // problem
        return Postorder( head -> right ); // problem
        printf( "%d\n", head -> data );
    } // if
}
```

Why is it wrong to write RETURN ? I want to know.

I think it will find head-> left all the way to the bottom, if head -> left is NULL, it will go back to the above one layer and start looking for head -> right, and finally output

Comment: You `return`. Don't.

Comment: how can you even return twice in the same block scope?

Comment: Remember that `return` means “exit the function with this result,” so if you return the value of the first recursive call you’ll never get to the next call.

Comment: code is executed top to bottom not bottom to top

Comment: rule of thumb: if you have two `return` in the same branch, at least one of them is a bug

Comment: Sorry you need to translate it to English, as it is written its very confusing

Comment: @TarickWelling: The normal case is a switch statement, where each `case` can have a `return`, all in the same block scope.

Comment: What value you `return` twice in `void` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` means "I'm finished here, so don't execute any more code in this function. So when the code encounters the first `return` statement it returns from the function, and doesn't execute the second call to `PostOrder` or the `printf` statement.

Off the top of my head, I suspect that simply removing the word `return` from both of those statements will fix the problem:

```
void Postorder( IntPtr head ) {
    if ( head != NULL ) {
        Postorder( head -> left );
        Postorder( head -> right );
        printf( "%d\n", head -> data );
    } // if
}
```

Comment: is this recursion ?

Comment: @Sheng -- yes, it's recursion; the function checks its stop condition, then calls itself with a reduced data set.

Answer (score 0):

You `return` before you `printf`.